# Windows form throwing error on execution

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

I have developed a windows form application to run in desktop computers.

This is simple system written in c# which uses Microsoft access as its database.

I have almost completed the code and was going to create setup file for installation on other system.

I did create setup file and install in one of the system, but unfortunately the application is unable to find the database and throws me the following error.
[image: Error Message when running application]

I have put the database file in the root folder of the project.

[image]

I have provided the following connection string throughout the application.

**In App.Config**

```
configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
 </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**In Application Classes**

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
```

This is the first time i have created the setup file and i am not sure where i am wrong.

Can somebody find answer to my question?

Comment: error box displayed above

Comment: How are you so sure that it is the not-finding-of-the-database which is the error? All we can see is an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' in the constructor of the form. That could be anything.

Comment: Oh god! You still have problems with that connection string?! :-)

Comment: because the error comes when i try to open the winodws form which populates combo box from database. Rest winodws which doesnot require database runs fine

Comment: i do, coz its not working for me at all...this problem is eating me up..

Comment: Well I am sure that your connection string doesn't point to the file in your project's root directory. It point to the project's *output* directory. Please post the complete stack-trace and also the code in the form's constructor.

Comment: Upload your project somewhere, and I promist that I'll fix it for you in seconds. (If uploading the whole project is not possible, at least create a sample project)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24710/discussion-between-amrit-sharma-and-md-unicorn)

Comment: Make file name extensions visible in Explorer

Comment: @MD.Unicorn can I see you in discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you see this error when you install your program. I think the configuration file (which you are reading the connection string from) is missing in the installation folder. Possibly something is wrong with your installation settings (output file, configurations, etc.). As I see in the image, your whole project is in `Program Files` folder! Which is the evidence of selecting whole source folder for the installation!

You should choose only `bin\Debug` folder for the installation, or if you are using Visual Studio Deployment Project, you should select `Project Output` for the files that are going to be in the `Program Files` folder.